Basic systemd timer won't work
I wan't a timer that runs a script every 10 minutes after the last script execution stops. Based on this site I created something
/etc/systemd/system/helloworld.timer   
[Unit]
Description="Hello World script"
    
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/helloworld.sh

/etc/systemd/system/helloworld.service  
[Unit]
Description="some"

[Timer]
OnUnitInactiveSec=24min
Unit=helloworld.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

After that I enable it using sudo systemctl daemon-reload and sudo systemctl enable --now helloworld.timer. The issue is that running their statuses says they don't work. It returns me with:
helloworld.timer - "some"
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/helloworld.timer; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: active (elapsed) since Tue 2024-11-26 15:00:03 CET; 2min 27s ago
Trigger: n/a

helloworld.service - "Hello World script"
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/helloworld.service; static)
Active: inactive (dead)

What's interesting is that starting the service with sudo systemctl start helloworld.service makes the timer work normal. Using OnCalendar instead of OnUnitActiveSec or OnUnitInactiveSec makes it work also. Making service type oneshot and timer WantedBy=timers.target doesn't help.

You’ve swapped the content of the .timer and .service files, swap the extensions and it’ll work. (The .timer file should contain the [Timer] bits and vice versa)
